# How to control header height in Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an older app that I am porting. In the app I had a non-standard header navigation made up of images and text over them.

The images used to be square, but there was some way I was able to make them rectangular by limiting the height of the header on the page.

I can't figure out how to do that. Where should I have such a setting and how should it look like?

Here is my header file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
>

 <Button android:id="@+id/home_header"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:text="Home"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_not"
  android:textSize="11dp"
/> 



 <Button android:id="@+id/learn_header"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Learn"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="11dp"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_not"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/businesses_header"
 />   


<Button android:id="@+id/questions_header"
 android:layout_width="0dp" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textColor="@color/white"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Plans"
 android:textSize="11dp"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_not"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learn_header"  />  



 <Button android:id="@+id/extra_help_header"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:text="More Help"
  android:textSize="11dp"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_not"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/questions_header"
 />   

</LinearLayout>
```

and I include that header in screens like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#1BB5E0"
        >
<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

How can I decrease the height of the header by about 50%?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "non standard header navigation"

Comment: @TimCastelijns I just meant that newer apps I think have a different/better way of handling this sort of thing...at least I've been told :)

Comment: What is "this sort of thing"? Can you show a pic maybe of what you mean

Comment: @TimCastelijns I just need to figure out how to limit the header height.